# I’m not sure what this is in my wall AC vent - fungus?

Tags: hvac, mold, dust

[image]Can someone help me identify what is this growing in my ac wall unit. I’m not sure if it is mold or dust.

Comment: Think it is some type of mold/fungus.  Dust is usually more general surface covering.  Would need testing to tell type of mold(don't think it is the bad kind) or just cleaning.

Comment: bleach it............